# reshape while converting Pandas Dataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas Dataframe, which has 4 rows and N columns, out to which I am taking 1 column as using it as feature to a classifier. Shown below

```
0    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
2    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

This column essentially is a `list` of 16 binary encoded features.

But when I feed this to my classifier, below error comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      clf.fit(X,y)
      X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
      ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
      array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I suppose the error is because the fit method wants a NxM matrix, while the shape it gets is

```
(4,)
```

So basically,

**I want to try to convert shape(4,) to shape(4,16)**

I tried below functions:

```
X = np.asarray(train_data['presence_vector'])
X.reshape((4,16))
X = train_data['presence_vector'].values
X.reshape((4,16))
X = train_data['presence_vector'].as_matrix()
X.reshape((4,16))
```

None of it worked.

Comment: You just can't reshape shape(4,) to shape(4,16) they have different numbers of elements. This can't be the solution to your problem (which is totally unclear btw).

Comment: https://coderpad.io/JWYMP4TX

Comment: I know programatically these 'may' have different elements, but I 'know' that it will always have same no. of elements. I just wanted to know if there is a solution without looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have tried the usual way. If there could be better solution than below

```
reshaped=[]
for l in X:
    reshaped.append(l)

X_new=np.array(reshaped)
print(X_new.shape)
(4, 16)
```